# SQL Server IF 0, add value for following date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing this query in MSSQL Server Management Studio, and I have run into a mental road block.  Let's say I have a few buildings and as they have come online I want to compare their production vs what they were forecasted,  P_AMOUNT and F_AMOUNT.  These are two separate databases combined into one with a query (The production db and forecast db that is).

[image]

So my problem here is.  I want to select the peak production here along side the forecast each B_ID.  Most of the buildings are like B_ID #2 and have a forecast amount, but occasionally there is one that does not.  Like B_ID #1.  How would I go about rolling the date one month forward for only the F_Date if the F_Amount = 0?

```
SELECT P1.B_ID, P1.P_DATE, P1.P_AMOUNT, F1.F_DATE, F1.F_AMOUNT
FROM DB1.Production P1
INNER JOIN DB2.Forecast F1
ON P1.DB_ID = F1.DB_ID
```

Comment: If there is no F_Amount for the current month OR the previous month, do you want to keep going back until you find a month that did have an F_Amount?

Comment: I want to progress through the months.  If a month has zero for forecast, then the previous months will also have the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested select of the Forecast table so that you get the minimum forecast date after the production date that has a value, something like:

```
SELECT MIN(F1.F_DATE) 
WHERE F1.F_DATE > P1.P_DATE 
    AND F1.F_AMOUNT > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of ways to solve your problem. One way is to rank each row based on `F_DATE` and when the `F_AMOUNT` value is zero, to pull the next row. Since you did not specify a version of SQL Server, I used syntax that would work in SQL Server 2005 or later.

```
With RnkItems As
    (
    Select B_ID, P_DATE, P_AMOUNT, F_DATE, F_AMOUNT 
        , Row_Number() Over ( Order By F_DATE ) As Rnk
    From SourceData
    )
Select R.B_ID, R.P_DATE, R.P_AMOUNT
    , R.F_DATE As [Original F_DATE]
    , R.F_AMOUNT As [Original F_AMOUNT]
    , Case R.F_AMOUNT
        When 0 Then R1.F_DATE
        Else R.F_DATE
        End As F_DATE
    , Case R.F_AMOUNT
        When 0 Then R1.F_AMOUNT
        Else R.F_AMOUNT
        End As F_AMOUNT
From RnkItems As R
    Left Join RnkItems As R1
        On R1.Rnk = R.Rnk + 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92a68/1)

If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use the new [Lead](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function:

```
Select B_ID, P_DATE, P_AMOUNT
    , F_DATE As [Original F_DATE]
    , F_AMOUNT As [Original F_AMOUNT]
    , Case F_AMOUNT 
        When 0 Then Lead ( F_DATE, 1 ) Over ( Order By F_DATE )
        Else F_DATE
        End As F_DATE
    , Case F_AMOUNT 
        When 0 Then Lead ( F_AMOUNT, 1 ) Over ( Order By F_DATE )
        Else F_AMOUNT
        End As F_AMOUNT
From SourceData
```

[SQL Fiddle Version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92a68/1)

The above two solutions rely on the stated requirement that you always go exactly one month ahead. If, however, you want to go the *first* month with a non-zero value (i.e., it could be multiple jumps), that's different:

```
Select S.B_ID, S.P_DATE, S.P_AMOUNT
    , S.F_DATE As [Original F_DATE]
    , S.F_AMOUNT As [Original F_AMOUNT]
    , Case S.F_AMOUNT
        When 0 Then (
                    Select Min( S2.F_DATE )
                    From SourceData As S2
                    Where S2.F_DATE >= S.F_DATE
                        And S2.F_AMOUNT <> 0
                    )
        Else S.F_DATE
        End As F_DATE
    , Case S.F_AMOUNT
        When 0 Then (
                    Select S1.F_AMOUNT
                    From SourceData As S1
                    Where S1.F_DATE =   (
                                        Select Min( S2.F_DATE )
                                        From SourceData As S2
                                        Where S2.F_DATE > S.F_DATE
                                            And S2.F_AMOUNT <> 0
                                        )
                    )
        Else S.F_AMOUNT
        End As F_AMOUNT
From SourceData As S
```

[SQL Fiddle Version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92a68/3)